# Issue with gloabl object

Tags: javascript

I have a global object declared at first line. Then filling the data into it using jquery getJSON. The issue here is I am getting empty object inside function slider, whereas inside getJSON it is printing proper data. Any idea whats wrong here?

```
var allslides = {};

$.getJSON("data/slides.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        allslides[key] = { image : val.image, title: val.title, desc:val.desc };
    });
    console.log(allslides); // First 
});

$(function(){
    slider();
});

function slider() {
    console.log(allslides); // second
}
```

Comment: because `getJSON` is asynchronous

Comment: Put your `$.getJSON` inside your `document.ready()` and call `slider()` only from within it's callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your call to `slider` into your `.getJSON` as it is asynchronous:

```
 $.getJSON("data/slides.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
     allslides[key] = { image : val.image, title: val.title, desc:val.desc };
    });
    slider();
});
```